# Reusing fragments in complex architecture

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I read a lot about fragments, and I use them all the time, but I came across one issue and I want to discuss different approaches, and pros/cons of them.

I have, for instance, 10 fragments and 1 activity that manages them.
What if I want to reuse some of the fragments? 
If I have some kind of wizard (i.e. onboarding) with features:
Create profile, login, setup everything before start...

Handling fragment button "next" won't take you to the same destination in all cases.

**First approach:**
FragA -> FragB -> FragC - FragD

**Reuse FragB:**
FragE -> FragB -> FragF = issue

*I don't want to go to FragC again. My logic demands that I go to FragF.*

It makes sense to notify activity WHO actually sent event, so activity will decide where to go next. Fragment should not be the one who chooses destination.

What do you suggest? Any smart pattern?
I prefer SingleLiveEvent for handling navigation.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am currently also trying to find a pattern to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/

Comment: How exactly would that help?

Comment: It's a totally new approach for handling navigation between fragments. If you are familiar with iOS's storyboard, you will understand promptly. It's almost the same thing.

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem. You still have to have the navigation inside the fragment itself. Therefore having still the same problem above. The only thing that that libraty solves are 1) no more writing fragment transactions by hand 2) supportcfor deep links in app

Comment: Maybe you could provide a snippet code of how that solves the above problem.

Comment: It does not solve the problem itself. Android actually does not have proper mechanism for solving my issue, except to make totally independent fragments and let activity to manage which fragment should be displayed next. 
Frag1 -> click on a button inside
Propagate event to activity
Activity decides what should be diplayed next (which fragment).
I use SingleLiveEvent for notifying activity about events.

Comment: Well then thank you for that knowledge. Highly appreciated

Comment: Hi, can you maybe post something of how you handle this issue by setting all the navigation to activity? It will really be appreciated thank you very much.